# Is there a word for losing something in order to gain some other thing?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

For example I want increase the speed of a memory system in a computer but this will cost more money or decreasing the capacity will also gain more speed.

So I have to lose capacity and money in order to gain speed.
More general example, **when losing one quality in return gaining other quality in more technical perspective usage**.

So I'm wondering if there is a word out there for this?

Comment: Sacrifice and compromise?

Comment: Compensate would be sufficient

Comment: Just to let you know: I agree with your and Lunakshc's selection! Trade-off is the perfect word and is often used in tech lingo to mean exactly what you had wanted to say.

Comment: There's an idiom **"to lose a quid and find a fiver"** that means *lose something to gain more in return*.

Comment: I think you can also use "Exchange" as a verb. Or use the expression "in exchange for".

Comment: Related, but I don't think it's a perfect match: **Robbing Peter to Pay Paul** [Wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rob_Peter_to_pay_Paul) - to take from one need to satisfy another.

Comment: it's not one word, but "What you gain on the swings, you lose on the roundabouts" http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it%27s+swings+and+roundabouts - infact, now I read it back, perhaps that pertains to equilibrium?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Trade-off**

> A trade-off (or tradeoff) is a situation that involves losing one quality or aspect of something in return for gaining another quality or aspect. More colloquially, if one thing increases, some other thing must decrease.

From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade-off

Comment: Or even just trade

Comment: Trade-off is the right word here as @Lunakshc answered.
Here is the usage of **trade-off** in your sentence: _In order to investigate the memory system you consider trade-offs of speed,capacity and cost._

Comment: Can also be used as a verb: _**trade off** memory capacity for CPU speed_. Or slightly more difficult to parse (slightly archaic style) _**trade** memory capacity **off** CPU speed_ -- this is only still correct because it's the origin of the noun-phrase _trade-off_. More up-to-date, you'd use the adverb _against_ with _trade_, e.g.: _**trade** memory capacity **against** CPU speed_.

Comment: @Rich thanks for the comments. what is the differences between **trade-off** and **sacrifice** from your point of view? From  this context so I simply could use this : **sacrifice** memory capacity for CPU speed. or?

Comment: @Adam they are almost equivalent.  While _trade-off_ implies a balance between the two, _sacrifice_ would tend to imply a larger loss or a one-way conversion or a hard limit.  To use a the computer analogy again, you could make a _trade-off_ between the CPU speed and memory, limited by your budget (you can always upgrade), but should you wish to use a smaller motherboard, you would _sacrifice_ expansionability as the smaller board has (for example) less PCI-e slots. In this case, there is still a benefit, but while you could get CPU and RAM by throwing more money at it...

Comment: ... you wouldn't be able to get more PCI-e slots on a smaller motherboard.  Note that you still get a benefit from making this choice.  The difference between the two is not great.

Comment: Nice! This word had totally slipped my mind! An excellent and very tech-appropriate word.

Answer (score 44):

> So I have to **sacrifice** capacity in order to gain speed.

Sacrifice: give up (something valued) for the sake of other considerations.

"[Sacrifice](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=sacrifice&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=dNkaWYbULMf48AeVqKewAw)," Verb, Definition 2, Google

> So I have to **compromise** capacity in order to gain speed.

Compromise: expediently accept standards that are lower than is desirable.

"[Compromise](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=compromise&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9dkaWaKaAcf48AeVqKewAw)," Verb, Definition 2, Google

Comment: thanks for the answer but sacrifice isn't a term often when killing animal or offering some thing?. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrifice

Comment: @Adam, that's for "sacrifice" the noun. We're looking at "sacrifice" the verb here (see my link above). And I do want to make a note that when not speaking in a religious context, most people will pretty much not think of the animal-killing/offering thing. Perhaps an image/meme search would be more appropriate: https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=firefox-b-ab&biw=1440&bih=791&tbm=isch&q=sacrifice+quotes&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6uef0qvTTAhUDl5QKHRwjDXwQhyYIIg.

Comment: @Adam  To back up TeacherKSHuang I do not often even think of animal sacrifice when I hear the word sacrifice, unless it is specifically in the religious context.  I have heard it in an emergency or war scenario. *He sacrificed himself so that the rest of the troop could get away,*

Comment: of course i commend your answer and up voted it, when sacrifice something i do not have to gain other thing in return or ?

Comment: Thanks for the back-up, @Willow! I hadn't know how to politely say, "Just trust me on this" without someone else chiming in :O :D.

Comment: +1, Sacrifice is a good word. See [Queen sacrifice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_sacrifice).

Comment: @Adam, no, you wouldn't. You're usually doing it for the sake of something else and not usually for personal gain, but you could also do it for personal gain in other areas such as in your example. But perhaps this is more a philosophical question than a linguistic one :O :D?

Comment: @Adam  Just because you make a sacrifice (time, money, effort), doesn't mean you gained a thing. If you sacrificed hours with your family to earn your degree in your subject, you could still fail to earn that degree. You still sacrificed the time and effort.

Comment: Similar to Queen Sacrifice mentioned by @LucianSava, There's the [Sacrifice Fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrifice_fly) in Baseball where the batter allows himself to be "out" while allowing a runner to advance and or score.

Comment: @Adam - There are [many](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sacrifice) definitions of _sacrifice_. Wikipedia is not a dictionary; you can't rely on Wikipedia to give you all possible definitions of a word.

Comment: @J.R. very true, I agree with you.

Comment: Sacrifice is also commonly used this way in chess. Sacrifice is the word that I thought of instantly when I saw this in the hot question list, and to me it is the most clear and obvious word for this question, and I'm surprised that this is not the accepted answer, although trade-off is a synonym for sacrifice used more often on business contexts.

Answer (score 7):

Not a singular word, but the phrase **“opportunity cost”** describes this situation well.

> “The opportunity cost of higher speed is a loss of capacity.”

Comment: @J... - What you're describing is an investment. The opportunity cost in that situation would be what you could have done with the money instead of buying the tractor, e.g. buying a barn for your business or 7000 Big Macs. That would probably be the route I would take with the money :)

Answer (score 5):

The verb **“to gambit”** comes from the world of chess and is sometimes employed in other field.

> “He gambits this in order to get that.”

The root of the word is the Italian ‘gambetto.’

In the Oxford English dictionary I could only find [gambit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gambit) as a noun, but I’m pretty sure I’ve seen it used as a verb in a phrase as well.

Comment: strictly speaking, a gambit gives you an advantage, which is not yet turned into a concrete benefit

Comment: I think of "gambit" as a noun, not as a verb.  "Gamble" is a verb, but its meaning is somewhat different.

Comment: Definitely a noun, and rather rooted in military tactics so that is the imagery that this word will invoke.  A gambit is usually some type of tactical strategy that makes an early sacrifice with the intent of it doing more damage to the enemy, either physically or psychologically, such that it will, in the end, turn to an advantage.

Comment: Chess commentators often use gambit as a verb: "He gambited the pawn."  (Disclaimer: just because someone in a "specialized field" uses a word in a certain way doesn't necessarily mean it's "proper English".)

Answer (score 2):

I kind of like the word 'compensation' for this, though there is some nuance.

It's used in chess as well: He sacrificed his rook but his position is better so he has compensation.

It's used in other contexts as well of course: I was compensated. (implies an original loss of something, potentially time or materials)

In your example: We will have less capacity, but this is compensated by an increase in speed.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional phrase is "a sprat to catch a mackerel". This dates from the mid 19th century—for example, see this [Oxford Reference](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100525243)—and is still current: for example as the title of a [book published in 2010](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11743033-a-sprat-to-catch-a-mackerel).

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I have added some references.